# Google Scripts/Sheets: How to aggregate row/objects based on values?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have lists of this format which I retrieve from  Google Analytics API and then want to output to a Google Sheet.

```
['dog', 'brown', 'mammal', 12],
['cat', 'black', 'mammal', 18],
['dog', 'brown', 'mammal', 7],
['goldfish', 'gold', 'chordata', 2]
```

I would like to aggregate the numbers at the end if the first three strings are identical and remove the duplicate entry. Such that:

```
['dog', 'brown', 'mammal', 19],
['cat', 'black', 'mammal', 18],
['goldfish', 'gold', 'chordata', 2]
```

I suppose one way to do this is to do it programmatically in plain Javascript/Google Apps Script, OR to use some library like UnderscoreGS OR to do it with some function in Google Sheets after adding the lists to a worksheet. Haven't been able to find a way to do this yet. Recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

Try this as starting point:

```
function groupBy(data, columns, sumCol)
{
  data = data || [['dog', 'brown', 'mammal', 12],
                  ['cat', 'black', 'mammal', 18],
                  ['dog', 'brown', 'mammal', 7],
                  ['goldfish', 'gold', 'chordata', 2]];

  columns = columns || [0, 1, 2]; // zero-based

  sumCol = sumCol || 3;

  var result = {};
  var row = []; 
  var key = '';
  var value = 0;
  var prev = 0;
  for (var numRow = 0, h = data.length; numRow < h; numRow++)
  {
    row = data[numRow];
    // join another row
    for(var numColumn = 0, w = row.length; numColumn < w; numColumn++)
    {
      if (columns.indexOf(numColumn) > -1)
      {
          key = '' + key + row[numColumn] + ',';

      }
      else if(sumCol == numColumn) { value = row[numColumn]; }                    
    }
    prev = result[key];
    // write result
    if (prev == undefined) { result[key] = value; }
    else result[key] += value;

    value = 0;
    key = '';

  }

  Logger.log(result);

}
```